# Comparing Sql Table Data on Visual

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am making a basic patient record system on visual studio (windows form application, c#).

When a user tries to insert the same firstname and surname, the application should give an error like:

> You can't insert the same name twice.

I just don't know how to get data directly from sql on visual . Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please point out what *visual* means.

Comment: i guess **Visual Studio**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code helps.
I have assumed that you are using Entity Framework

```
var newPatient = ...;    
if
( 
    Context.Patients.Count
    (
        x=>
        x.Name==newPatient.Name && 
        x.Family==newPatient.Family
    ) > 0
)
    MessageBox.Show("This is an existing patient");
```

---

**Edit (Based on your comment):**

```
var newPatient= new Patient();
newPatient.Name = textBox1.Text;
newPatient.Family = textBox2.Text;
if
    ( 
        Ort.Grid.Count
        (
            x=>
            x.Name==newPatient.Name && 
            x.Family==newPatient.Family
        ) > 0
    )
        MessageBox.Show("This is an existing patient");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you be more specific about this code? I should write this in foreach loop right? I dont use entity framework but I just learn how to use it. I just need what should ı write the "..." part. I used this code inside "foreach (var user in ort.grid)" where ort is an object of My Entity Frame Work and grid is the table name. Could be algorithm mistake what ı write. I am apprantice. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK my friend. So, you can write your code somthing like the edit above.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked But I want to point out that the code which you show me earlier;It didnt work. But  I changed "> 0" part with ">1" and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have recently added the newpatient to the list , yes you should check the count>1 but in the case  you have not added the newPatient to list yet you should check count>0. Any way I up-voted you and wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make Firstname and lastname as primerykey combine in your db table, that will not allow duplicate... but making names as primary key is not good practice because may two patients have same first and last names

Comment: Two times correct but the result is..? - Hint: Do a Select count(*) where name1=name.. and check for an empty result before writing the record! Then talk with the user is he really want to create a duplicate. Or check the birth date; this will hardly be the same, too..